# Cannot Shut Down on Ubuntu - Ubuntu 16.04 and Win 10 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, kernel, shutdown

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows 10 pre-installed Desktop. Everything looks ok but I cannot shut down on Ubuntu- Every time when I shut it down it will stuck with a error like 'end kernel panic: not syncing: fatal exception in interrupt', please see the attached screen shot picture.[screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKMwp.jpg)  which I have to force to press poweroff button on machine to turn it off.

By now I can only when I finish using Ubuntu : either restart and choose to log in on windows OS and shut down normally(since my Windows works normally), or press the physical shutdown button on the machine when I was trying to shut down and got frozen under ubuntu afterwards

FYI: Here are some info about the desktop and system: 
GPU: NVIDIA gtx-1080, 256 GB SSD, 2T HDD (100GB SSD and 500 GB HDD for Ubuntu)
Ubuntu: '/' and 'swap' on SSD, '/home' on HDD

Any help will be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

sync writes anything still in cache to the hard drive (or SSD).  To eliminate that as a problem, type:

`sudo sync` - May not require sudo but it can't hurt.

To shutdown not using the task bar GUI, open a terminal session and type

`sudo shutdown -h` - to halt and power off

`sudo shutdown -r` - to reboot

As the system is being shut down in an orderly manner, note the messages that are listed on the screen.  This will provide more info on what is causing the panic.

I see you updated your question to include a screen shot.  I'd suggest running a few passes of memtest to eliminate memory as a possible problem.  And if you are overclocking, it might not hurt to set the BIOS back to the defaults at least for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem before.
You may need to upgrade its package. Just go to terminal and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then you can shut down and won't face the problem